How to share the locators which are page constructor to other page in playwright?
export class AlertsPage {
    readonly page: Page;
    readonly alertsToBeApprovedTab: Locator;
    readonly alertsToBeReviewedTab: Locator;
    readonly allAlertsTab: Locator;
    readonly tableHeader: Locator;
    readonly context: Context;
    readonly alertToast: Locator;
    readonly selectActions: Locator;
    readonly applyButton: Locator;
    readonly waiveButton: Locator;
    readonly commentTextArea: Locator;
    readonly getAlertCheckRowLocator: (nthIndex: number) => Locator;
    readonly getAlertNumberRowLocator: (nthIndex: number) => Locator;
    readonly selectActionItem: (actionMenu: string) => Locator;
    readonly HambergerIcon: (columnname: string) => Locator;
    readonly filterIcon: Locator;
    readonly filterInput: Locator;
    readonly applyfilterButton: Locator;
    readonly noRecords: Locator;
    readonly filterAlreadyAppliedOrNot: (columnname: string) => Locator;
    readonly filteringOperator: Locator;
    readonly resetfilterButton: Locator;
    readonly loadingIcon: Locator;
    readonly pagewiseLastRecord: Locator;
    public numberofRows: Number;
    public cellvalue: string;
    readonly getEachCellValue: (nthIndex: Number, columnname: string) => Locator;
    readonly operatorFilter: Locator;
    readonly selectOperator: (opearatorText: string) => Locator;
    //RuleCode
    readonly searchFieldInRuleListBox: Locator;
    readonly selectAllInRuleListBox: Locator;
    readonly selectcheckBoxOptionInRuleListBox: (option: string) => Locator;
    readonly columnIcon;

    homePage: HomePage;

    constructor(page: Page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.alertsToBeApprovedTab = page.getByText("Alerts to be Approved")
        this.alertsToBeReviewedTab = page.getByText("Alerts to be Reviewed");
        this.allAlertsTab = page.getByText("All Alerts");
        this.tableHeader = page.locator("//*[contains(text(),'Alerts')]//..//..//..//..//..//..//*[@ref='eText' and text()='Customer ID']");
        this.homePage = new HomePage(this.page);
        this.context = this.context;
        this.alertToast = page.locator("//*[@role='alert']");
        this.selectActions = page.locator("//*[contains(text(),'Select Actions')]");
        this.applyButton = this.page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Apply' });
        this.waiveButton = this.page.getByLabel('WaiveButton');
        this.commentTextArea = this.page.locator("//textarea");
        this.getAlertCheckRowLocator = (nthIndex: number) => {
            return page.locator("//div[@aria-rowindex=" + nthIndex + "]/div/div/div/div").first();
        };

        this.getAlertNumberRowLocator = (nthIndex: number) => {
            return page.locator("//div[@aria-rowindex=" + nthIndex + "]/div//span");
        }
        this.selectActionItem = (actionMenu: string) => {
            return page.locator("//*[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='" + actionMenu + "']");
        }
        this.HambergerIcon = (columnname: string) => {
            return page.locator("//*[text()='" + columnname + "']/../../span/span")
        }
        this.filterIcon = page.locator("span[aria-label='filter']");
        this.columnIcon=page.locator("//span[@aria-label='columns']");
        ////*[text()='Customer ID']/../../span/span
        this.filterInput = page.locator("//*[@placeholder='Filter...']");
        this.applyfilterButton = page.locator("//*[@ref='applyFilterButton']");
        this.noRecords = page.locator("//*[@class='no-data-to-display-message']");
        this.filterAlreadyAppliedOrNot = (columnname: string) => {
            return page.locator("//*[text()='" + columnname + "']/../span[@ref='eFilter' and contains(@class,'ag-hidden')]");
        }
        this.filteringOperator = page.locator("//*[@aria-label='Filtering operator']");
        this.resetfilterButton = page.locator("//*[@ref='resetFilterButton']");
        this.loadingIcon = page.locator("//*[@ref='eLoadingText']");
        this.pagewiseLastRecord = page.locator("//*[@ref='lbLastRowOnPage']");
        //columnId: Number=alertNo,Review State=reviewState, Description: desc, Customer ID=cust, Rule Code=wLCode, Approved=app, Date=createDate
        this.getEachCellValue = (nthIndex, columnName) => {
            return page.locator("//div[@aria-rowindex='" + nthIndex + "']/div[@col-id='" + columnName + "']");
        }
        //const screenshot = this.page.screenshot();
        this.operatorFilter = page.locator("//*[@role='listbox']/div");
        this.selectOperator = (operatorText: string) => {
            return page.getByText(operatorText);
        }
        this.searchFieldInRuleListBox = page.getByPlaceholder("Search...");
        this.selectcheckBoxOptionInRuleListBox = (option: string) => {
            return page.locator("//*[text()='" + option + "' and contains(@class,'checkbox')]");
        }
        this.selectAllInRuleListBox = page.locator("//*[text()='(Select All)']/..");
    }

Now  I have search page.. if I search the alert and click the search results.. it will again open new page..
async ClickSearchResults(testInfo: TestInfo, enteredValue: string, context: Context) {
    if (await this.noRecords.count() > 0) {
        console.log("No Records");
        testInfo.fail();
    }
    else {
        const [newPage] = await Promise.all(
            [context.waitForEvent("page"),
            this.searchResultsRow(enteredValue).first().click()
            ]
        );

        

        const title = await newPage.locator(this.titleLabel).textContent();
        var screenshot = await this.page.screenshot();
        await testInfo.attach("Search Results navigation", { body: screenshot, contentType: 'image/png' });
        await newPage.locator(this.supportingDocumentIcon).nth(2).click();
        await newPage.locator(this.plusIcon).click();
        const notesString=this.generateRandomString(15);
        await newPage.locator(this.addNotes).fill(notesString);
        await newPage.locator(this.saveButton).click({ delay: 1000 });
        screenshot = await this.page.screenshot();
        await testInfo.attach("Notes Added", { body: screenshot, contentType: 'image/png' });
        //expect(await newPage.locator(this.alertDialog)).toHaveText(data.NotesAddedSuccessfulMessage);
        await newPage.locator("")

        
        expect(await newPage.locator(this.notesDescription)).toBe(notesString);
        await newPage.locator(this.returnToRoaster).click();
    }

Few of the locators is common for page and newPage..I wanted to use the locators in page constuctor here in the newPage as well. Is it possible?
especially these are
this.getAlertCheckRowLocator = (nthIndex: number) => {
return page.locator("//div[@aria-rowindex=" + nthIndex + "]/div/div/div/div").first();
};
this.getAlertNumberRowLocator = (nthIndex: number) => {
    return page.locator("//div[@aria-rowindex=" + nthIndex + "]/div//span");
}
this.selectActionItem = (actionMenu: string) => {
    return page.locator("//*[@class='mat-option-text' and text()='" + actionMenu + "']");
}
this.HambergerIcon = (columnname: string) => {
    return page.locator("//*[text()='" + columnname + "']/../../span/span")
}

because these are dynamic locators i dont want to write directly in the [newPage]. any suggestion really helpful..

XPath is discouraged, for starters... I would not want to have to maintain this test suite. Seems like a much bigger problem than sharing a few locators. If locators are shared among two pages, I might factor them out to a third utility class, or just duplicate a little bit of code. But yeah, it's rather opinion-based and depends on your larger design approach.

can you pls give more details? do u think that sharing locator maintenance is high? I might factor them out to a third utility class, can u pls give this as well some thoughts
